Unable to burn NFTs in my collection
I've minted a NFT collection using the nft-campaign-runner but forgot to set the execution to known addresses and instead got a collection that was minted to new addresses with a gift code. Since that is not what I was trying to do, I want to destroy the collection now. Before I can do that, I need to first burn all NFTs within the collection, but I get a "permission denied" error.

This is the collection: https://assethub-polkadot.subscan.io/nft_collection/150
This is a batch transaction with the individual calls failing: https://assethub-polkadot.subscan.io/extrinsic/0x6d10d1bc45345e2eed589e4bd5ce6187c9b9da69521ab30dd09223f1b476744c

I am a bit confused, because I thought that I should be able to burn NFTs as the collection owner.

I think it is the admin. You can change it as the owner by calling set_team: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/substrate/frame/nfts/src/lib.rs
